# SQL Query with IF,AS and LIKE

Tags: mysql

My mySQL query is:

```
 $userlist_sql = "SELECT id,user_type,retailerId,subdealerId,dealerId,assigned_role, 
IF( user_type = '5', (select name from retailer where retailer.id=users_dealers.retailerId), (select name from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=users_dealers.subdealerId )) AS from_name,
IF( assigned_role = '6', (select name from dealers where dealers.id=users_dealers.dealerId), (select name from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=users_dealers.dealerId )) AS assigned_name
FROM users_dealers  WHERE from_name LIKE '%a%' OR assigned_name LIKE '%a%'";
```

The above query shows error like:

> Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'users_dealers.from_name' in 'where clause'.

I want to search dealers name with a character. How to write the query. Please help me.

Comment: And when you googled that error message without your specific names you learned--? Please read & act on [ask] and [mcve]. And when you simplify your code until you get no error? And what parts of your goal can you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error occurs due to `like` statement. You need to add `(')` in your statement.and also you can't use `from_name` as a field for this you have to create this as a subquery first.

Like as  following Code:

```
select * from (SELECT 
id,user_type,retailerId,subdealerId,dealerId,assigned_role, 
IF( 
user_type = '5', 
(select name from retailer where retailer.id=users_dealers.retailerId), 
(select name from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=users_dealers.subdealerId )
)
AS from_name,
IF(
assigned_role = '6', 
(select name from dealers where dealers.id=users_dealers.dealerId), 
(select name from sub_dealers where sub_dealers.id=users_dealers.dealerId )
)
 AS assigned_name
FROM users_dealers) t1  WHERE t1.from_name LIKE '%a%' OR t1.assigned_name LIKE '%a%'
```

Comment: Yes, The error showing "Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'users_dealers.from_name' in 'where clause'"

Comment: I got your error and update your my answer check this one now.

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much addy. Your code save my time. :)